# 301 redirect to page number

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

On my website these are the same:

```
http://example.com/tags/cloud/page1?id=foo
http://example.com/tags/cloud?id=foo
```

So I'm doing a 301 redirect like this (the goal is to apply this only for **page1**):

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)page1(.*)$ /$1$2 [R=301,L]
```

This works fine for page 1 but there are two problems:

- `http://example.com/tags/cloud/?id=foo` (there's a forward slash after
  cloud)
- The rule executes on every page number which starts with 1, no just page1. So `/cloud/page124?id=foo` becomes `/cloud/24?id=foo` and so on.

How can these two be fixed? The rule should only apply to page1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not an include an optional `/` before `page like this:

```
RewriteRule ^(?:(.+)/)?page1/?$ /$1 [L,NC,R=301]
```

Make sure to clear your browser cache before testing this change.

Comment: Thanks but page1 is not used as a traditional parameter, so it never has a ? before it. Also page 1 never has a / after it and the id=foo param is totally optional.

Comment: Sorry, yes should've tried. It now works for page11, page123, page1000 etc. Cool! But there's still a forward slash after cloud (for page1) - tags/cloud/?id=foo. It will work fine, but is it too much effort to hide it?

Comment: Althought the chance is slim, yes, page MAY come at the start. If someone's name is "page" it WILL come at the start!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/91407/discussion-between-yeti-and-anubhava).